# How to overrite appsettings.json or appsettings.<envrionment>.json file(s) programtically using .net core web api with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, appsettings

**Current problem with a scenario:** Our application code was deployed in dev environment with dev api service (Third party api service : DEV). Now, due to maintainence this third party service is down in dev environment and our testing is blocked. So architect decided point to QA and redeploy the code into DEV environment.

Until we push the changes into DEV team has to wait for testing.

**To avoid this situation, what we are looking here is ,**

Read these file(s): `appsettings.json` or `appsetting.<environment>.json` and loaded in UI with editable way. When there is a change required like above scenario, we change and update our `appsettings.json` or `appsetting.<environment>.json` files.

This way we save our time to redploy this file with new changes.

But our question here is, all our data from `appsettings.json` or `appsetting.<environment>.json` these file(s) loaded during startup. Later, we update and loaded the file in environment but how these values are going to read it through any of the service in code?

Hope you are getting my scenario and expecting your valuable suggestions

Comment: Just use a different file? Or load another one that overwrites the settings? You can also specify the settings as environment variables or command line arguments. There's nothing special about `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.production.json`. They're just JSON files. The reason `production.json` "overrides" the previous file is that it's registered after that file. Nothing more. In .NET Core's configuration middleware you can have multiple configuration sources. Adding a setting in a later source overrides the value specified in previous sources

Comment: I'm struggling to actually understand the question and figure out what you are actually asking here.

Comment: The "environment"-specific file is controlled by the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable and can be `Production`, `Staging` or `Development`. You can set one of those values and create a file with the appropriate name. There's no need to use extra code. Nor is there any need to edit the files at runtime. Create and deploy the files you really want, and set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

Comment: It depends on how actually you are using the settings - if you read settings only one time at startup you can't do much except  reloading app after config changes, in some cases app can refresh settings from files in runtime (check as is for example) or you can use options pattern with [`IOptionsMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ioptionsmonitor)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request, you will need to use a design pattern, such as *wrapper*.

Create a singleton service that holds all settings in properties. Do not use `IConfiguration` directly anywhere in the services, instead switch to the wrapper. Thanks to this you can control the source of settings, and overwrite the settings by overwriting properties in the wrapper. You don’t have to modify source files and reload the entire application, thanks to this solution.

Also remember about proper caching and encapsulation - if you’re caching the values somewhere, make sure you have that in mind.